# PM2 is running extra processes

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

We have build an iOS app which uses the RESTful web APIs written in Node which is hosted on Google Compute Engine and the database which we are using in Mongo DB. We also have Nginx configured as web server which routes the requests to Node js service.

Now on Google Compute Engine Node js is running behind load balancer with auto scaling feature ON. Web services are used by iOS app users as well as by the background jobs which are sitting on another instance on Google Compute Engine.

We have started our Node js service using PM2 with number of cores set as 8 as we have 8 core machines on Google Compute Engine.

Now the issue is when I start PM2 it runs 8 processes but over the period of time it shows more than 8 processes running sometimes and when I try to kill PM2 using the command 'sudo pm2 kill' it kills all the 8 processes which were started during the start of Node js service but still when I check for the processes running using the command 'sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i 'listen' I see that some of the processess are still running and have occupied the port on which Node js service is running. So, before I could restart my Node js services I need to kill those extra PM2 processes and then only I can restart PM2 back again.

Below is my Nginx config

```
upstream node {
    server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.dev.yellfy.com;
    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        client_max_body_size 300M;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    }
}
```

Please help me understand as what could be the reason behind extra processes PM2 running.

For reference below is the technology stack I am using

Technology Stack

Node js - 5.5.0
PM2 - 1.0.0
Mongo DB -  3.0.4
Nginx - 1.6.3
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Comment: I have faced similar problem with pm2 when using cluster, try killing PM2 process by finding its pid **ps -aux | grep PM2** it should kill all the processes

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pm2 kill` option (it isn't mentioned in [the docs](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)), but perhaps `kill` is the equivalent of UNIX's `kill -9` command, effectively killing the process itself and maybe not its spawns. Do you observe the same behaviour if you use the `pm2 stop all` command? (or the `restart`, `delete`, whatever you intend to achieve option)? Personally, I have yet to find a reason to add `sudo` for anything other than maintaining `pm2` itself (which for me is just the global install)

Comment: Can you try updating pm2? This feels like a recent fixed bug (can't get my hand on the issue).

Comment: when I start PM2 it runs 8 processes but over the period of time it shows more than 8 processes running sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pm2 to stop the processes.

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Then to stop

```
pm2 stop app.js
```

When you stop pm2 via kill you are not allowing pm2 to shut down gracefully. If your server reboots I think your processes will restart.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/